# Google Play Store No connection

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Why when I enter Google Play Store using my LG-P875 phone, it shows only "No Connection Retry"? A few days ago I was deleting some apps and other stuffs to save up my storage space, and I wonder if I actually deleted sth that relates to the connection to Google Play Store. Please help me find a solution!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! In order to help you, we will need much more details – e.g. are you connected via mobile network or WiFi? Did your network show a connection? Are you able to access the network with a browser in those cases? Which Android version runs on your device?

Comment: I've had that problem once. Maybe it's inapplicable for you, but is the phone rooted? If yes? Did you install an application for removing ads once> (e.g. AdAway) - You have to update the hosts files. Also what you could try is to set your DNS to 8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8

Answer (score 0):

Many people right now have been experiencing this issue over LTE networks. As we speak I am also experiencing this issue and I am only able to use any google application over wifi using a Samsung Galaxy S5 -> Tmobile

http://www.phonearena.com/news/Google-Play-Gmail-Maps-and-other-Google-services-hit-by-global-outage_id56208

http://www.droid-life.com/2014/05/16/google-services-experiencing-issues-how-are-yours-acting/

EDIT: After about a day without google services unless on wifi, they have been restored on my device.